# How to put a variable url in curl_setopt_array

Tags: php, curl, backend

I would like to pass the postcode as a variable in this curl API. All the examples I've seen are with a fixed URL. I tried to read all the documentation I found, but no luck, that is why I am asking here.

I get the result if I select a static URL like:

```
"https://postcodejp-api.p.rapidapi.com/postcodes?postcode=1110032"
```

but not with

```
"https://postcodejp-api.p.rapidapi.com/postcodes?postcode=$postcod"
```

I tried to put it inside the function, outside, but I am clueless.

```
<?
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
<form class="" action="" method="get"enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <label for="">Enter your Post Code</label>
  <input type="text" name="postcode" value="">
  <button type="submit"><strong>Search</strong></button>
</form>
  </body>
</html>


<?

if(isset($_GET["postcode"]))
{
  $postcod = $_GET["postcode"];
  $url = "https://postcodejp-api.p.rapidapi.com/postcodes?postcode=$postcod";
  $curl = curl_init();
  curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => $url,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
    CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
    CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
    CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
    CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
      "x-rapidapi-host: postcodejp-api.p.rapidapi.com",
      "x-rapidapi-key: API HERE"
    ),
  ),);

  $response = curl_exec($curl);
  $err = curl_error($curl);
  $dat=json_decode($response,true);
  curl_close($curl);

  if ($err) {
    echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
  } else {

  echo $dat["data"][0]["allAddress"];
  }

}

?>
```

Comment: It's not the reason for your problem I don't think, but just to note that `enctype="multipart/form-data"` is not necessary in your `<form` tag unless you are allowing the user to upload a file.

Comment: Anyway I'm afraid there is no obvious reason, from the code you've shown, why this would not work. Have you done any debugging? Check the value of $postcod and $url before you send the cURL request, just to see if they are set the way you expected. e.g. `$postcod = $_GET["postcode"];
  $url = "https://postcodejp-api.p.rapidapi.com/postcodes?postcode=$postcod"; var_dump($postcod); `var_dump($url);`. This will output those variables for you, then you can see if they look ok or not.

Comment: I got it, the first time started the script of php i did not put <?php I put insted <?
I change it, and now works, hours took me hahaha, i was 5 months without using php, i was learning other languages and i forgot the little things, Thanks anyways!!